# unable to fetch saved data from core data

Tags: ios, core-data

When i search for saved data from core data, it is giving me old saved data while retrieving it. Need help to find  my mistake

```
- (void)retrieveDataFromCoreData
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"VitaminData" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

     NSError *error = nil;
     NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request
     error:&error];

    NSString *matchFound = nil;
    matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     if ([objects count] == 0) {
     //matchFound = @"No matches";
     } else {
     matches = objects[0];
     matchFound = [matches valueForKey:@"userdetails"];
     }

NSLog("retrieved data : %@",matchFound);
}
```

Comment: Check the other objects in the array , not only the first.

Comment: You are not searching here. Just fetching first object each time.To search, set `NSPredicate` to `NSFetchRequest` specifying the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch request has no predicate. That will cause it to fetch all of the `VitaminData` entities in your datastore.

Give it a predicate, and (probably) also some sort descriptors. Then iterate over the results. Note you should also check that `objects` is not `nil` after your `-executeFetchRequest:`. If `objects` is `nil`, there's an error in your fetch request, and you should look at the contents of `error`.